# VirtualBox no longer works after uninstalling Docker on Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, docker

VirtualBox was working fine on my Windows 10 machine.  For another project, I had to install Docker.  After that work was done, I uninstalled Docker.  Now my VirtualBox VMs are no longer working (some kind of VT-X problem?).  I checked the BIOS and the VT-x settings are enabled.

Can anyone advise why uninstalling Docker would cause this, and how to get VirtualBox working again.  The machine is an E470 Thinkpad.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get VirtualBox running again, complete the following steps:

- Open the "old" Windows Control Panel -> Programs and Features
- On the left side choose "Turn Windows features on or off:

[image]

- Deselect "Hyper-V" in the list of features:

[image]

- Click "OK", let Windows deinstall Hyper-V and reboot at end
- After reboot you have to **reinstall/repair** your installation of VirtualBox with the original installer!
- Reboot again and it should work

Answer (score 5):

> After that work was done, I uninstalled Docker. Now my VirtualBox VMs
>   are no longer working (some kind of VT-X problem?).

When you installed Docker it required you to also install Hyper-V

> Can anyone advise why uninstalling Docker would cause this, and how to
>   get VirtualBox working again? The machine is an E470 Thinkpad.

You need to uninstall Hyper-V.  You won't be able to run a 64-bit guest within a VirtualBox VM until you do that

> Hyper-V is automatically enabled on a Docker for Windows install.

[Microsoft Hyper-V](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/)

Comment: You could always just use Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3):

Installing `Docker Desktop 2.3.0.5` broke my `VirtualBox 6.1.14` Windows guests (Windows host)

Even after uninstalling Docker they were still broken

- Tried uninstalling `Windows Subsystem for Linux`
- Resolution was to uninstall the Windows Feature `Virtual Machine Platform`

I arrived at the solution by checking `Event Viewer` => `Setup` to discover what changes Docker installer had made

```
Selectable update VirtualMachinePlatform of package Microsoft-Windows-HyperV-OptionalFeature-VirtualMachinePlatform-Disabled was successfully turned on.

Initiating changes to turn on update VirtualMachinePlatform of package Microsoft-Windows-HyperV-OptionalFeature-VirtualMachinePlatform-Disabled. Client id: DISM Package Manager Provider.
```

Notes

1. Guests were running HyperV paravirtualisation
2. HyperV was already uninstalled when started troubleshooting

Comment: It works on `Win10 Home 20H2`. Thanks